# android app with online database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create an android app that gets displays write-ups to everyone using the app. I'll keep updating the content (articles) that the users will be seeing. What are the prerequisites to implement this app? What all should I learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going for a free database,try [hostinger.in](http://www.hostinger.in). I implemented a similar app. Manually store the details in database and use a custom listview to display the articles heading.Learn how to get data from server.You could use a php script for that. This php file would convert and return your data into JSON format and you could extract your data from JSON string recieved.

Comment: Thankyou. I heard I need to use SQLite for creating the database. Is that true ? and then i need to put the database online from where my app will be retrieving it. Right? I'm sorry I'm a very much beginner :P I've made a beginner android app and know SQL and created a project in JAVA that uses Oracle as backend.

Comment: use the above mentioned site. They would provide you with a free domain name which has got SQL databse and other options. In the database options create a new database and provide a login id and password for that. Go to phpMyAdmin and create a table. You don't need to use sql queries.simply add columns and insert data. Upload a php file in file manager option. Provide me your mail id,i can mail you the php code to fetch data and return a JSON format of that.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. kg941119@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You could learn about HTTP GET in Java if you're trying to retrieve data from your own website. You could also use a Parse backend, and use a parse get query to retrieve string data from your Parse Object. The string data would be your articles so you can just go on the parse website, add a new row, and paste in your articles.

Those are the easiest routes I can think of.

Comment: I do not want to retrieve it from a website. Rather I would be updating it in the database directly.

Comment: Alright, then I think you should check out Parse. www.parse.com

Answer (score 0):

There is ksoap library for android which you could use to send/get data from a webservice. To learn more about ksoap visit the following link:
https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/

here is a tutorial for consuming webservices using ksoap in android:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242

or if you want to push the updates you can use Google Cloud Messaging to update various content in your app.